# wpcf7 and GTM event listener issue

Tags: google-tag-manager, contact-form-7

I have a Tag set up in GTM, custom html like this;

```
<script>
document.addEventListener( 'wpcf7submit', function( event ) {
    dataLayer.push({
      'event' : 'wpcf7successfulsubmit',
      'CF7formID' : event.detail.contactFormId
    });
}, false );
</script>
```

Doesn't work. Not at all. So I put a script on the page.

```
var wpcf7Elm = document.querySelector( '.wpcf7' );
wpcf7Elm.addEventListener( 'wpcf7submit', function( event ) {
    dataLayer.push({
      'event' : 'wpcf7successfulsubmit',
      'CF7formID' : event.detail.contactFormId
    });
}, false );
```

from a basic example on contactform7.com. This, in GTM preview, triggers fine. The first time it triggers the tag once, the 2nd and subsequent times it triggers twice (implying that both my script and the GTM tag are firing). Guessing at a problem with the event bubbling up. I put the specific selector `wpcf7Elm` into the tag's custom html but this doesn't work - like the first example.

I have no problem with running from a script but the problem is firing the tag twice so that the analytics shows two events. I would like to use GTM but at the moment the only solution I can see is to go back to on page scripts.

Can anyone suggest what I might be doing wrong? Just to note that I have disabled all plugins and that I am using, on a different page, a wpcf7 event listener successfully (from a script on the page) to perform a presentation function.

Comment: Just a note to add; I'm still mystified as to why this is happening but I've added scripts to the container for each form to target that container directly. This works fine. So I don't use GTM tags to add the listeners but I am using triggers to monitor the events and another tag to send them to the analytics.  I think the core of my problem might be multiple forms. I can see why the 2nd code example would fail ('which wpfc7?') but it still appears that the events are not bubbling to the document level.

Comment: Have you tried the firing options in GTM? Set it to `once per page` if this doesn't satisfy your needs you can use the sessionstorage and set there a value that you can check, usually i do this when cf7 doesn't work as it should.

Comment: Because it's necessary to find a solution and move on, I've ending up making the wpcf7 tags as scripts on the page as the OP but deleting the GTM Custom html and then using a GTM UA to send them to analytics. The *very* strange thing that was happening was the event would fire once on the on-page script, the 2nd time it would fire that tag and the GTM tag, the 3rd time it would fire 4 more times, the 4th, 8 etc in some kind of infernal loop.  It's actually easier to put the code straight onto the page and you can get the event from the outer container of the wpcf7 form thus making each unique.

Comment: ....which didn't actually answer your question, yes, in the live version I have set the important tag (UA tag) to only fire `once per page`.